# WPF Adding control to a specific area of UserControl dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

Good afternoon,

I seem to be having a simple issue with WPF.

After googling for few good hours, I couldn't find anything that would resemble what I'm looking for.

To put simply, I'm looking for a way to define an area in my custom UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <TemplateArea x:Name="FormControls">

    </TemplateArea>
</UserControl>
```

Then do this inside Window, Panel, etc. that uses my custom control:

```
<TheUserControl>
    <TemplateArea x:Name="FormControls">
        <TextBox/>
    </TemplateArea>
</TheUserControl>
```

.. and as a result, TextBox will be directly pasted inside of my custom control.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the ContentPresenter?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @PatrikValkovič while it seems to be similar to my issue - I don't it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to create a dependency property that holds an array of controls, and inside your control you bind it to an `ItemsControl`:

#### child.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="RootControl">
  <...>   <!-- your other UI -->
    <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=RootControl}" /> 
    <!-- style the items and/or panel as you wish -->
  </...>
</UserControl>
```

#### child.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Items", typeof(Observable<UIElement>), typeof(Child),
    new PropertyMetadata(new Observable<UIElement>()));
```

#### host.xaml

```
<Page>
  <...>
    <my:Child>
      <my:Child.Items>
        <TextBox/>
        <CheckBox/>
      </my:Child.Items>
    </my:Child>
  </...>
</Page>
```